# Как, используя ARKit сделать, чтобы поверхностью для якоря была невидимая стена?

Tags: swift, arkit, augmented-reality

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в пространстве образовалась еще одна, так сказать комната-куб, на невидимые стены которой можно бы было "повесить" объекты на ARAnchor.

Допустим комната 6х4, а нужен куб 2х2.

Answer (score 0):

Во фреймворке ARKit, есть метод [add(anchor: ARAnchor)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/aranchor).

А при создании невидимого якоря, используйте в ARAnchor пропертю [transform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/aranchor/2867981-transform).